# Scraping from website that needs authentication using Java

Tags: java, web-scraping

I found this code on an old form and I am trying to get it to work but am getting this error:

```
File: /net/home/f13/dlschnettler/Desktop/javaScraper/RedditClient.java  [line: 46]
Error: cannot access org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
  class file for org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal not found
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;


public class RedditClient {
    //Create a new WebClient with any BrowserVersion. WebClient belongs to the
    //HtmlUnit library.
    private final WebClient WEB_CLIENT = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    //This is pretty self explanatory, these are your Reddit credentials.
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    //Our constructor. Sets our username and password and does some client config.
    RedditClient(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        //Retreives our WebClient's cookie manager and enables cookies.
        //This is what allows us to view pages that require login.
        //If this were set to false, the login session wouldn't persist.
        WEB_CLIENT.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    }

    public void login(){
        //This is the URL where we log in, easy.
        String loginURL = "https://www.reddit.com/login";       
        try {

            //Okay, bare with me here. This part is simple but it can be tricky
            //to understand at first. Reference the login form above and follow
            //along.

            //Create an HtmlPage and get the login page.
            HtmlPage loginPage = WEB_CLIENT.getPage(loginURL);

            //Create an HtmlForm by locating the form that pertains to logging in.
            //"//form[@id='login-form']" means "Hey, look for a <form> tag with the
            //id attribute 'login-form'" Sound familiar?
            //<form id="login-form" method="post" ...
            HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='login-form']");

            //This is where we modify the form. The getInputByName method looks
            //for an <input> tag with some name attribute. For example, user or passwd.
            //If we take a look at the form, it all makes sense.
            //<input value="" name="user" id="user_login" ...
            //After we locate the input tag, we set the value to what belongs.
            //So we're saying, "Find the <input> tags with the names "user" and "passwd"
            //and throw in our username and password in the text fields.
            loginForm.getInputByName("user").setValueAttribute(username);
            loginForm.getInputByName("passwd").setValueAttribute(password);

            //<button type="submit" class="c-btn c-btn-primary c-pull-right" ...
            //Okay, you may have noticed the button has no name. What the line
            //below does is locate all of the <button>s in the login form and
            //clicks the first and only one. (.get(0)) This is something that
            //you can do if you come across inputs without names, ids, etc.
            loginForm.getElementsByTagName("button").get(0).click();

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String get(String URL){
        try {
            //All this method does is return the HTML response for some URL.
            //We'll call this after we log in!
            return WEB_CLIENT.getPage(URL).getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a new RedditClient and log us in!
        RedditClient client = new RedditClient("hutsboR", "MyPassword!");
        client.login();

        //Let's scrape our messages, information behind a login.
        //https://www.reddit.com/message/messages/ is the URL where messages are located.
        String page = client.get("https://www.reddit.com/message/messages/");

        //"div.md" selects all divs with the class name "md", that's where message
        //bodies are stored. You'll find "<div class="md">" before each message.
        Elements messages = Jsoup.parse(page).select("div.md");

        //For each message in messages, let's print out message and a new line.
        for(Element message : messages){
            System.out.println(message.text() + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Not really sure how to fix it since I'm not very familiar with scraping in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add [xml-apis](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01) to your classpath

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this.

Comment: It seems that you don't have org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal in your classpath so you need to add the jar that contains this class in your classpath

Comment: Thanks that worked and it now compiles with no errors but when I run it now I get this error: 

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
 at RedditClient.<init>(RedditClient.java:13)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)`...

Comment: you need to add also commons-codec in your classpath then http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10

Comment: The error is now `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/NoHttpResponseException
 at RedditClient.<init>(RedditClient.java:13)` 
I assume I need to add another jar to my class path?

Comment: yes try this http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/CredentialsProvider` Another one

Comment: Same error. I also tried the newest version before you got the chance to reply.

Edit: It works now. I had the wrong path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113451/discussion-between-dan-s-and-nicolas-filotto).